# How to auto start openvpn (client) on Ubuntu CLI?

Tags: command-line, openvpn

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. I have an `*.ovpn` file that works if I type:

```
sudo openvpn client.ovpn
```

Now I would like to start up `openvpn` when I boot the computer.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. Download the `OpenVPNConfigFile.ovpn`. Note that you can rename the file to anything you like.
2. Move the ovpn file to `/etc/openvpn`
3. `cd /etc/openvpn` folder and enter `sudo nano yourserver.txt`

   ```
   your_server_user_name
   your_server_passowrd
   ```

   Save and Close
4. `sudo nano OpenVPNConfigFile.ovpn`

   Find `auth-user-pass` and add `yourserver.txt` next to it so that it becomes

   ```
   auth-user-pass yourserver.txt
   ```

   This will allow you to skip entering your credentials everytime you start openvpn connection
5. Rename `OpenVPNConfigFile.ovpn` to `OpenVPNConfigFile.conf`

   ```
   sudo mv OpenVPNConfigFile.ovpn OpenVPNConfigFile.conf
   ```
6. `sudo nano /etc/default/openvpn`

   Uncomment `AUTOSTART="all"`
7. `sudo service openvpn start`

   You should see a message saying that you are connected. The connection will be established every time you start your computer.

Comment: If you're running systemd you will need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` before restarting the service

Comment: Is this the for a server ?

Comment: what about if my config doesn't have user and pass?

Comment: @HenryNavarro in that case, you just skip to step 5 and no adjustments needed.

Answer (score 6):

The `openvpn` package comes with an init script `/etc/init.d/openvpn`. This script automatically sets up connection for every `.conf` (mind the extension) file in `/etc/openvpn`.

Found this based on information here: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#startup

> If you install OpenVPN via an RPM or DEB package on Linux, the installer will set up an initscript. When executed, the initscript will scan for .conf configuration files in /etc/openvpn, and if found, will start up a separate OpenVPN daemon for each file.

Answer (score 4):

I got a bit stuck on this and ended up writing out all of the instructions for setting it up with systemd manually.

This worked for me using Ubuntu 16.10 and openvpn 2.3.11

#### Setting up your vpn to run from bash

These examples use expressvpn but most would work the same way

Download your vpn provider's ovpn config file e.g. *my_express_vpn_amsterdam_2*.**ovpn**

move that to `/etc/openvpn/` and rename it to end in **.conf**

```
sudo mv ~/Downloads/my_express_vpn_amsterdam_2.ovpn /etc/openvpn/amsterdam-2.conf
```

Your VPN provider will provide you with a username and password for connecting over openvpn. Save the userename and then password each on their own line

```
sudo vim /etc/openvpn/express-vpn-crednetials.txt
# add these lines
YOUR_VPN_USERNAME
YOUR_VPN_PASSWORD
# save the file
```

now edit `/etc/openvpn/amsterdam-2.conf`
look for a line that says `auth-user-pass` and replace it with the path to your credential file

```
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/express-vpn-crednetials.txt
```

Test your config! Start openvpn like this

```
sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/amsterdam-2.conf
```

openvpn should connect without asking for username or password

#### Remove existing (broken) service config for openvpn

```
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/openvpn.service
```

#### Set up openvpn to run as a systemd service

The config that came with openvpn was broken so I removed it and created a new one based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148990/using-openvpn-with-systemd/149003#149003?newreg=53ca53879fcc489f94304f91bbc82ab3)

Create systemd service for openvpn

```
sudo vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@service
```

add this config:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On %I
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
PrivateTmp=true
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/openvpn/%i.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn/%i.pid --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config %i.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the `%i`is used as a wildcard so that this service can be used for multiple vpn configurations. Set it up for the `amsterdam-2.conf` file that we created earlier

```
sudo systemctl start openvpn@amsterdam-2.service
```

the systemd service should now be running on the amsterdam vpn. check its status like so

```
sudo systemctl status openvpn@amsterdam-2.service
```

you should see several lines of output ending in `Initialization Sequence Completed` and your vpn should be running.

Hope this helps! related reading:

- [How to start 2FA using OpenVPN with systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206058/how-to-start-2fa-using-openvpn-with-systemd/206490#206490)
- [How to start the OpenVPN client service on Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639855/how-to-start-the-openvpn-client-service-on-ubuntu-15-04)
- [Using OpenVPN with systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148990/using-openvpn-with-systemd/149003#149003?newreg=53ca53879fcc489f94304f91bbc82ab3)

Comment: I execute your steps and things work as demonstrated by the "systemctl status" but after reboot when running the same status command it says "Active: inactive".  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to have a un hacker way of doing it, but this will have to do for now.

1. Create file  myopenvpn in  `/etc/init.d/`

   ```
   nano /etc/init.d/myopenvpn
   ```
2. Insert into myopenvpn and save:

   ```
   # OpenVPN autostart on boot script

   start on runlevel [2345]
   stop on runlevel [!2345]

   respawn

   exec /usr/sbin/openvpn --status /var/run/openvpn.client.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/client.conf --syslog openvpn
   ```

SOURCE: [How to auto start OpenVPN client in Debian 6 and Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.hackerway.ch/2012/12/11/how-to-auto-start-openvpn-client-in-debian-6-and-ubuntu-12-04/#comment-79)

Answer (score 2):

There are prebuild scripts if you take a look at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-client@.service`

So you accutally just need 2 steps:

1. Copy your config file to `/etc/openvpn/client/`: `mv client.ovpn /etc/openvpn/client/client.conf`
2. Start the service: `sudo systemctl start openvpn-client@client.service`

If there's a file `/etc/openvpn/client/ttt.conf`, so the service command should be `sudo systemctl start openvpn-client@ttt.service`

Answer (score 0):

If your client.ovpn file doesn't contain a password, then use the following:

1. Copy your `client.ovpn` file to `/etc/openvpn/`

   `sudo cp -i client.ovpn /etc/openvpn/`
2. Go to the openvpn folder

   `cd /etc/openvpn/`
3. Rename the file from `client.ovpn` to be `client.conf`

   `sudo mv -i client.ovpn client.conf`

- Now it's ready,

  - To connect use:

    `sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn start`
  - To stop openvpn use:

    `sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn stop`
  - To reconnect use:

    `sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn restart`
  - To check your ip:

    `curl ifconfig.co`

This should work on startup.

`Note:` when you put your computer to sleep you should restart or stop Openvpn to be able to connect to the internet

This answer derived from `@Robert Polson` post.

This is tested on `Ubuntu 22.04`

Comment: Does client.conf is mandatory name ?