# How do I auto start openvpn (client) on bootup in Ubuntu?

Tags: openvpn

Im a beginner and need help with step by step instructions please

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to auto start openvpn (client) on Ubuntu CLI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229800/how-to-auto-start-openvpn-client-on-ubuntu-cli)